# BizTalk and Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, biztalk

Can Visual Studio 2017 be used for BizTalk project work?

I seemed to get issues when I open a solution file that relates to BizTalk using Visual Studio 2017.
i.e. Errors re. the .btproj files.

> Error is "the application which this project type is based on was not found."
>   Please try this link for further information: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=299083&projecttype=EF7E3281-CD33-11D4-8326-00C04FA0CE8D

This link doesn't seem to specifically mention Visual Studio 2017 be used for BizTalk project work.

Comment: I wondered why this question is "put on hold" ? This is yes / no type of answer to this question ?

Comment: This site https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9e0a4bbf-c13f-4027-a85f-8ec1351937c2/vs2017-biztalk-project-templates-install?forum=biztalkgeneral    says BizTalk 2016 it is VS 2015 only, you cannot use VS 2017

Comment: This is a very good question. I am surprised why it is negatively voted. Going to upvote it.

Answer (score 4):

Each version of BizTalk requires a specific version of Visual Studio. Currently the latest version is BizTalk 2016, which requires Visual Studio 2015 see [Hardware and Software Requirements for BizTalk Server 2016](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/install-and-config-guides/hardware-and-software-requirements-for-biztalk-server-2016)

When BizTalk 2020 comes out it will be Visual Studio 2019. So no, you can't use Visual Studio 2017 for BizTalk development

Note: You will have needed to run the BizTalk Setup and installed the Developer SDK after you have installed the correct Visual Studio.

- BizTalk 2020 projects require Visual Studio 2019
- BizTalk 2016 projects require Visual Studio 2015
- BizTalk 2013 R2 projects require Visual Studio 2013
- BizTalk 2013 projects require Visual Studio 2012
- BizTalk 2010 projects require Visual Studio 2010

With Visual Studio 2019 you also have to install an extension, see [Biztalk 2020 - Project not showing in Visual Studio 2019](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/25ed1057-afd8-4d36-bf41-80020a2e2ae7/biztalk-2020-project-not-showing-in-visual-studio-2019?forum=biztalkgeneral)

Comment: BizTalk projects are install thru the extensions of VSTudio.

Comment: @PhilippePecqueur For Visual Studio 2019/BizTalk 2020, yes, earlier version not.