# Is there a way to determine which version of BizTalk a .btproj uses?

Tags: biztalk

I'm trying to open a .btproj but it says I have an incompatible version of BizTalk. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57797746/18433023) post says you have to have a specific version of Visual Studio foreach version of BizTalk.

...Can the version of BizTalk be derived from the .btproj or any of the other files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, from the solution file.

e.g BizTalk 2013 R2 uses Visual Studio 2013

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00
# Visual Studio 2013
VisualStudioVersion = 12.0.31101.0
```

However you should be able to open up an earlier version with a later version, and it then does an upgrade of the solution.  So open it with the appropriate version of Visual Studio for the BizTalk environment you want to target.

If the solution has already been moved to a new version of BizTalk, then the source you have there, is NOT the latest version of that code.